# Lock to Laucher does not work

Tags: unity, launcher

I have faced with problem ...
By some reason when I press Lock to launcher for some application it does not work ... I have found pattern, it is happened only to application that was previously installed removed and then installed newer version.
In such case I cannot lock application to Launcher ...

What can cause such issue ?

Comment: Could you give one or more examples? Locally installed or globally? Also please add the output of `ls ~/.local/share/applications` to your question.

Comment: @JacobVlijm Thanks for suggestion. I have found in ~/.local/share/applications/jetbrains-webstorm.desktop that there was saved an old version of webstorm ... I changed it to newer version and the problem gone. Thanks again

Comment: Ah, I had a hunch that would be it. You can answer your own question, someone else might profit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Jacob Vlijm an issue was found in ~/.local/share/applications/**jetbrains-webstorm.desktop** that there was saved an old version of **Webstorm** ... Seems like when I pressed **"Lock to Launcher"** the file ~/.local/share/applications/**jetbrains-webstorm.desktop** was not overridden, but in this file was wrong path to **Webstorm**